# jquery validate rails dynamically named form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, jquery-validate

I have a form dynamically named by rails like "edit_project_id" where ID changes. How to enable jquery validate for any form "edit_project%" ?

I tried to pass name to my javascript/coffee as data attribute according this
http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript but with no luck

I've added this tag to pass name variable

```
<%= content_tag "div", id: "form_name", data: {name: "edit_user_#{@project.id}" } %>
```

then in my coffee I try to work with it but no luck

```
jQuery -> 
$('#form_name').data('name').validate(
     lang: 'sk'
     rules:
        'project[amount]': min: 1
     highlight: (element) ->
        $(element).parent().addClass 'state-error'
        return
     unhighlight: (element) ->
        $(element).parent().removeClass 'state-error'
        return
);
```

at the end I want my coffee script to validate each form which is for edit_project doesnt matter ID..if it is possible with some wildcard or passing variables, both is ok for me, just dont know how to do that

Comment: I'm not really sure what that first line of your JS is – the $ sign is just a different way to call jQuery, isn't it? Also, that Railscast is before turbolinks I think, so if you're using turbolinks then you should need to call $.document.ready().

Comment: this is what i use on new project and works, so I tried just to change the way how to get element name

`jQuery -> 
 $('#new_project').validate(
   lang: 'sk'
   rules:
    'project[amount]': min: 1
   highlight: (element) ->
      $(element).parent().addClass 'state-error'
      return
     unhighlight: (element) ->
      $(element).parent().removeClass 'state-error'
      return
 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a form dynamically named by rails like "edit_project_id" where ID changes. How to enable jquery validate for any form

FYI - the `.validate()` method does not need to be attached to the `id`.  You can use [any valid jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you can imagine.  The only requirement is that the selector can only target ONE form, not a group of forms.

So if you only have one form on the page, you can simply target the `<form>` tag itself...

```
$('form').validate({ ...
```

If that's not acceptable, then inspect the rendered DOM and construct a reliable jQuery selector based on some other set of criteria.

---

To target the `data` attribute when it "starts with" something like `edit_user`...

```
$('[data^="edit_user"]').validate({ ...
```

And if you have more than one `form` matching the selector, wrap it in an `.each()` and `.validate()` will be attached to all matching forms..

```
$('[data^="edit_user"]').each(function() {
    $(this).validate({ ...
```

Comment: great, changing jquery to target validate to form works and helps so I can use one javascript for each form in my views